# How can I iterate over a Perl array reference?

Tags: perl, arrays, reference

I have an array that is a member of a structure:

```
$self->{myArray} = ["value1", "value2"];
```

And I'm trying to iterate over it using the following code:

```
my @myArray = $self->{myArray};
foreach my $foo (@myArray){
    #Do something with the using $foo
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the 'foreach' loop is executed only once (when I would expect it to execute twice, since @myArray has two elements: "value1" and "value2").

When I check the @myArray array size, I get that its size is 1. What am I doing wrong in this code?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. I have accepted the first answer...

Comment: You may wish to read the Data Structures Cookbook: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html It has examples showing how to create and access many different data structures.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I believe that:

```
$self->{myArray} returns a reference.
```

You want to return the array:

```
@{$self->{myArray}}
```

Comment: Ahh beaten to the punch by FM:)

Comment: And just in case you want to know how to do this for a hash ref:

%{$self->{myHash}}

Answer (score 11):

`$self->{myArray}` is an array reference. You need to dereference it.

```
my @myArray = @{ $self->{myArray} };
```

In situations like this, the `Data::Dumper` module is very helpful. For example, if `@myArray` were not behaving as expected, you could run this code to reveal the problem.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@myArray);
```

Answer (score 7):

`$self->{myArray}` is an array reference, not an array - you can't store actual arrays inside a hash, only references. Try this:

```
my $myArray = $self->{myArray};
for my $foo (@$myArray){
   # do something with $foo
}
```

You also may want to have a look at [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).